# Are correlated errorbars useful for regression fitting?

Tags: regression-coefficients

Let's say I have a dataset that roughly fits a 2nd order polynomial but I trying to fit it using a linear regression (see image). The error in my y measurement depends on y, but the coefficient of variance for every data point is similar. If I ignore the errorbars I get one fit, and if I include them as weighting I get another. Because the error is correlated, the weighted fit is heavily influenced by the smaller values.

Looking at the fits and the data, I'd say the simple linear regression better fits the data, but then I am completely ignoring the errorbars. In general, is there a way to find a best fit using correlated errorbars?

The plot is fake data but represents a real scenario I am encountering. The errorbars are one standard deviation and in a typical measurement I get something like 1 ± 0.5 and 100 ± 50 for y values, depending on x.

[image]

Comment: I must be missing something: why are you not using weighted fitting to the second order polynomial?

Comment: The data is just random data with the same features as the real data I have. It should fit a linear trend, not a quadratic, but I was lazy in making the plot so I just chose quadratic data.

Comment: Then all you need is weighted linear regression: the true weights would be the reciprocals of the relevant population variances. If those are unknown, then it is typical to use the reciprocals of the relevant sample variances, i.e., reciprocals of the squares of the relevant sample standard deviations. So you are all set.